# tcp sprious retransmission. what's wrong?

Tags: tcp, raw-sockets

I made a python code that redirects to another site with raw socket.

summary:
1. client sends HTTP GET request to any webserver.
2. the gateway redirects to prepared site using raw socket.
3. but, client sends HTTP requests again after accepting 
HTTP 302 Access Denied packet.. again and again

pcap file link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e1RLsPmiDwNvGk6G471WwGt8x1Sckx0L

[image]

what's likely be the cause?
I can't figure out..

Comment: I uploaded wrong picture..wait... - corrected!

Comment: You should give us the code you are using to redirect